# In nms_ransack, we keep getting infected, what is the cause!

Tags: no-more-room-in-hell

In NMS_Ransack, there is a message in the bathroom of the grocery store stating clearly: Water infects people.

I constantly get infected although i'm not bitten at all, i'm a good player and don't get much damage at all most of the time, but on this stage, i keep dying due to infections that occur out of the blue.

Can anyone give a clear explanation of what is going on in this stage, which water is doing that infection and where, i haven't been able to find a clear concise answer to this question anywhere on the web!